# Does a Zimbabwean traveling with a United Nations laissez-passer need a visa to visit UK?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am a Zimbabwean with a [United Nations laissez-passer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_laissez-passer) (UNLP).  Using the UNLP, do I need a visa to visit UK?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the purpose of your visit to the UK.  What is it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use your national passport -- and therefore you need a visa -- [if the trip is not for official UN purposes](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance-ecb08/ecb08-what-are-acceptable-travel-documents-for-entry-clearance):

> UN Laissez-passer This allows the holder to travel to the United Kingdom on official business without a national passport or entry clearance. However, when holders travel to the UK for any other reason, they should use their national passports (and visas will be required by visa nationals).